# How can I set default and change price with checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to create an interface of a website which has a varying price dependent on whether check boxes are checked and which has a default value if none are selected.

The varying value is in a table which has the id 'Level1Price' which I want to default to a value of '£5.11' if neither of the two check boxes are checked and the value to chage if either one or both are selected and where the two chekc boxes on their own would hold a different value each.

The two check boxes have the id's 'partner' and 'children'. When no checkboxes are checked (for the purpose of this demonstartion) the value of 'Level1Price in the table should be 5.

If just the 'partner' checkbox is checked the value of 'Level1Price' is 10.

If just the 'children' checkbox is checked the value of 'Level1Price' is 12.

If both checkboxes are checked the value of 'Level1Price' is 20.

```
var partner = document.getElementById("partner");
var children = document.getElementById("children");
function calc()

if (!partner.checked && !children.checked) 

{
  document.getElementById('Level1Price')element.innerHTML = 5;


} else if  (partner.checked && !children.checked) 

{

document.getElementById('Level1Price')element.innerHTML = 10;


} else if (!partner.checked && children.checked) 

{     
  document.getElementById('Level1Price')element.innerHTML = 12;


} else if  (partner.checked && children.checked)

 {

  document.getElementById('Level1Price')element.innerHTML = 20;

 }
```

This is the code that I thought would work and i'm struggling. I apologies if I have made rookie mistakes i'm quite new to this and couldn't find any working resolutions anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

These are the chekcboxes that I want to help change the vale in the table.

```
<div class="addition">
<label for="partner">+ Partner:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="partner" id="partner" value="partner" required>
</div>

<div class="addition">
<label for="children">+ Children:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="children" id="children" value="children" required>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the Table data I want to be able to populate

```
   <tr>
   <td scope=col id="Level1Price" value="5.11"> <b></b> <br/> per month</td>
   <td scope=col id="Level2Price" value="9.97"> <b></b> <br/> per month</td>
   <td scope=col id="Level3Price" value="14.06"> <b></b> <br/> per month</td>
   </tr>
```

Is it possible to automatically update without the need for a 'calculate' button?

Comment: Can you share you HTML too please? And i'm not sure `document.getElementById('Level1Price')element.innerHTML = 12;` is syntax correct... (**('Level1Price')element**)

Comment: is the default £5.11 or £5?

Comment: I tried this too: document.getElementById('Level1Price').value = 12; would that make a difference?

Comment: you mean document.getElementById('Level1Price').innerHTML = 12 ?

Comment: could the default be 5.11, I just put 5 as it's easier to remember.

Comment: What is the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: I am unable to get the values from my JS into the webpage. This is likely to be some problem with the syntax of my javascript, maybe not effectively linking it to my html document correctly or a combination of errors.

Comment: @SC123 what are you getting in the console?

Comment: I think you are syntactically wrong in line document.getElementById('Level1Price')element.innerHTML It should be document.getElementById('Level1Price').innerHTML

Comment: I have tried this thankyou, I think i have a problem with this communicating correctly into the table format. @vibhor1997a

Answer (score 0):

Provided your HTML looks like:

```
<span id="Level1Price"></span>
```

then:

```
document.getElementById('Level1Price').innerHTML = 20;
```

will result in your HTML being:

```
<span id="Level1Price">20</span>
```

Basically you just have a syntax problem (remove the erroneous 'element' text).

Comment: this hasn't worked in my document I think the figure being in a table messes it up:(

Answer (score 0):

There is a small syntax error in your code. for better understanding, I have attached a fully functional code to meet your requirement.

**Kindly refer the following code.**

```js
var partner = document.getElementById("partner");
var children = document.getElementById("children");

function calc() {
  var val = 5;
  if (partner.checked && !children.checked) {
    val = 10;
  } else if (!partner.checked && children.checked) {
    val = 12;
  } else if (partner.checked && children.checked) {
    val = 20;
  }

  document.getElementById('Level1Price').innerHTML = val;
}
```

```html
Partner: <input type="checkbox" id="partner" /> <br /> Children: <input type="checkbox" id="children" /> <br /> Level1 Price:
<span id="Level1Price"></span>
<br />
<button onClick="calc()">Calculate</button>
```

If still you find any issue or have any doubt feel free to comment, I will update my answer. TIA

Comment: This is great thanks, I am unable to get the price to transfer into the table it sits in would this be a problem? Is it possible to automatically update without the need for a 'calculate' button?

Comment: @SC123 you can call the function at the click of the checkbox(both of them) for that instead at the click of calculate button.

Comment: Would the fact the data is in a table affect it's functioning?

Comment: @SC123 If you can provide complete code or information then a better solution can be provided.